# What is the best to give a role to user jda who has joined indtantly JDA

Tags: java, api, discord

So i used the following code

```
public class UserJoinModule extends ListenerAdapter {
        @Override 
        public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
            Member user = event.getMember();
            Guild guild = event.getGuild();
            Role role = guild.getRolesByName("Non Verified", true).get(0);
            guild.addRoleToMember(user, role).queue();
            
        }
    }
```

There was no error the event was registered, guildId was given the member id was and the role was also given.(I used sytem.out.println to find)

but the `guild.addRoleToMember(user, role).queue();` never runs.Is there something im missing to add role the bot has admin role too.

Answer (score -1):

Solved: initiate a `Member bot = guild.getSelfMember`
This makes the bot know that is there and can interact